# 0 is a limit point for $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ in countable complement topology

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence

In countable complement topology on $\mathbb{R}$, prove that $0$ is a limit point of $A=\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$?

Also prove that is there no sequence in $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ that converges to $0$.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A neighbourhood of $0$ in the co-countable topology is of the form $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$, where $A$ is countable (and does not contain $0$). This always intersects $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ in uncountably many points even. In general, $p$ is a limit point of $X \setminus \{p\}$ iff $\{p\}$ is not open, in any topological space.

If $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, define $O = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{x_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, which is open in the co-countable topology (by definition) and is a neighbourhood of $0$ that does not contain any poiunts of the sequence. So the sequence does **not** converge to $0$ (because then every open set that contains $A$ should contain almost all points of the sequence).

Answer (score 0):

Due to the nature of the topology you're utilizing on $\mathbb R$, it is more "natural" to use the open set definition of limit points, rather than sequences. The use of sequences to detect limit points is best when your space is Hausdorff (it is not since $\mathbb R$ is uncountable).

Here is the general definition: A point $x$ in $X$ is a \textit{ limit point} of $S$ if every neighborhood of x contains at least one point of S different from x itself.

Comment: If $x_n=0$ for all $n,$ does the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in N}$ converge to $0$ ?

Comment: @user254665 how about any sequence in R∖{0}?